# Laravel/Lumen Custom Polymorphic relationship type

Tags: laravel, lumen, polymorphic-associations

I have 1 project developed in Laravel 5.5 which is the web administrator, and I also have a project developed in Lumen 5.5 which is the api for mobile applications.

We are handling polymorphic relationships, but I found a problem, the web administrator handles the name of a model in Spanish, and the api in English, so the api is not able to find the related elements.

When I create a record from web administrator the type saves it as App\Especie, but the api tries to find App\Specie.

I tried with `protected $morphClass` in the model in the API, but it didn't work. and I have not been able to find any solution to the problem

Comment: You're gonna have to force a language here; code doesn't really care which language (i.e both `App\Species` and `App\Especie` are perfectly valid), but it needs to be consistent. Sidenote, "Species" is singular and plural noun, so you can use that as a model name and Laravel will handle it, but Specie is not a word :P

Comment: are you saving the model name in the database? because you can access the "Especie" data from the "Especies" table, by putting ```protected $table = 'especies'```  at the Specie model.